# Compare two different length data.frames in R [r]

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having trouble trying to compare two different length data.frames i.e.

```
id<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
a<-c(2,4,20,8,7)
b<-c(1,3,4,7)
c<-c(3,6,9,12)
d1<-data.frame(id,a)
d2<-data.frame(b,c)
```

What I'm trying to do is sum the values of `d2$c` for each `d1$id` that fulfills the condition `d1$a>=d2$b`. I've been trying with `dplyr` by doing this.

`d1<-mutate(d1, sumb = sum(ifelse(a>d2$b,d2$c,0)))`

However I'm getting this

```
Warning message:
In a > d2$b :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I know it's incorrect using this code. I've checked tons, literally TONS of forums looking for the answer. The output I want should look something like this.

```
| id | a  | sumb| 
|----|----|-----|
| a  | 2  | 3   |
| b  | 4  | 9   |
| c  | 20 | 30  |
```

Just to explain for `id="a"`, `a=2`. This `a=2`is only greater than the first value in `d2$b[1]=1` so I just need the `sum(d2$c[1])=3`. However, for `id="c"`, `a=20`. `a=20` is greater than all the values in `d2$b`. Then I need the sum of all values in `d2$c` for `id="c"` which is `sum(d2$c)`.

I hope this is clear enough for you to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the most sensible method is using a cartesian join or a series of for-loops.

Using [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki)'s non-equi joins, we can obtain this by changing the `data.frame`s to `data.table`, non-equi merge and then sum of the columns

```
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
a <- c(2, 4, 20, 8, 7)
b <- c(1, 3, 4, 7)
c <- c(3, 6, 9, 12)
d1 <- data.frame(id, a)
d2 <- data.frame(b, c)

library(data.table)
#Could have used "d1 <- data.table(id, a)" and "d2 <- data.table(b, c" instead of setDT
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)

#Non-equi join, following by sum using dt[i, j, by, ...] syntax. (see link wiki in link)
d2[d1, on = .(b <= a), allow.cartesian = TRUE][, sum(c), by = id]
```

## Edit: Workaround for 2e31+ rows

A problem that might occur when using cartesian joins is the [vector length limitation of R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html). One possible work-around for this (and there are likely myriads) is to avoid joining altogether, and use the fast subsetting aspect of `data.table`, as shown below

```
setkey(d1, 'id')
d1[.(unique(id)), d2[a >= b, sum(c)], by = .EACHI]
```

### explanation:

The query goes as follows:

1. `setkey(d1, 'id')` reorders `d1` according to `id`, which allows using the `i` argument.
2. `d1[.(unique(id))]`: Once we've reordered we can utilize fast binary subsetting in the first argument. Here it is saying "give me all rows with `id`'s contained in `unique(id)`.
3. While (2) seems unnecessary, it is necessary for the `by = .EACHI` argument, which lets `data.table` know we want to perform the action in `j` seperately for each `i`.
4. letting `j = d2[a >= b, sum(c)]` performs all the calculations. `data.table` will automatically index `a` such that the comparison `b <= a` can be performed using binary search.

This should be somewhat if not much faster than subsetting using a regular for-loop. Albeit slower than using a cartesian join.

## Edit: Alternative using Rcpp

Looking at the comment from @caalbarracinb, the number of summations to be done seems to be quit large, using either of these methods. Avoiding duplicate summation will speed up this calculation quite handsomely.
One method for doing this is to assume that `a`, and `b` are sorted in ascending order, and iterating over values in a smart way.
Below is my (likely quite inefficient) example of how one could achieve this with an Rcpp function.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export(rng=false)]]
NumericVector sumCompar(NumericVector a, NumericVector b, NumericVector c){
  // assumes b, a are sorted in ascending order according to sum.
  int na = a.length(), nb = b.length(), j = 0;
  NumericVector sums(na);
  auto sum = 0.0;
  // Iterate over a, sum over elements in b until a < b. 
  // Once this happens we've summed over all values in the specific category.
  for(int i = 0; i < na; ++i){
    while(j < nb){
      if(a(i) < b(j))
        break;
      sum += c(j);
      j++;
    }
    sums(i) = sum;
  }
  return sums;
}
```

which we can use as

```
aa <- d1[, .(a = max(a)), by = id][order(a), a]
idd <- d1[, .(a = max(a)), by = id][order(a), id]
bb <- d2[order(b), b]
cc <- d2[order(b), c]
data.table(id = idd, sum = sumCompar(a = aa, b = bb, c = cc))
```

Now to make a (horrible) comparison of speed, we could use microbenchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cart_join = d2[d1, on = .(b <= a), allow.cartesian = TRUE][, sum(c), by = id],
  subset = d1[.(unique(id)), d2[a >= b, sum(c)], by = .EACHI],
  rcpp = {
    out <- data.table(id = d1[, id[1L], by = id]$id, 
                      sum = sumCompar(a = aa, b = bb, c = cc))
  }
)
#output:
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 cart_join 2224.201 2457.6510 3972.440 3063.801 5195.200 12475.101   100
    subset 3251.001 3573.3510 5638.339 3994.851 7969.900 13460.502   100
      rcpp  530.701  645.3015 1055.473  735.201 1016.551  9147.501   100
```

And looking at the median time, we can see the Rcpp implementation is quite a bit faster in this example.

**But** the important thing here, is that this speed difference will be much greater for larger inputs, as it does not have to perform unnecessary comparisons as `a`, `b` and `c` are assumed to have the correct order.

Comment: Hi there! I've tried learning `data.table` but when using your code with my full data I get this this message error. 
`Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit)`
Do you have any idea of how can I solve this? It would be very useful.

Comment: Hi @caalbarracinb, what you're experiencing is the internal limitation of vectors in `R` ([reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html)). Basically R can't interpret the answer properly. I'll update my answer with a possible work-around that will still utilize some (if not most) of the optimization.

Comment: Looking at your, @caalbarracinb, error causes me to think raw `data.table` implementations are likely going to be similarly slow. I've added an example using `Rcpp` which will be much faster for this specific problem. Note the code can be compiled using `library(Rcpp); sourceCpp(code = codestr)` where `codestr` is a string containing the cpp code in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a function computing the sums to each element of `d1$a`.

```
fun <- function(x, y) sum(y[x > y])
d1$sumb <- sapply(d1$a, fun, y = d2$c)
```

This can be rewritten as a one-liner, with an anonymous function.

```
d1$sumb <- sapply(d1$a, function(x) sum(d2$c[x > d2$b]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  group_by(row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(sumb = sum(d2$c[d2$b < a])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, a, sumb)
```

You should see results like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  id        a  sumb
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         2     3
2 b         4     9
3 c        20    30
4 d         8    30
5 e         7    18
```

Also notice that you asked for condition `d1$a>=d2$b`, but your sample results are based on `d1$a>d2$b`. I followed your sample.

Comment: Okay, so this definitely works.Thanks!. But is taking way too long. In real life d1 has 663.591 rows and d2 has 74.640 rows. I tried with little subsets and it's fine. But with full data it has been running for 15 minutes so far. Any clue of why is taking that time?

Comment: @caalbarracinb dplyr is not the most efficient solution for very large datasets. data.table is a better solution.

Comment: adding to bellmaneqn, `data.table` is optimized for **very** big data manipulation (in their answers they often refer to situations with 100+ Gb or even Tb of data). R works by creating copies of data at evaluation. `data.table`s avoid this behaviour where able. (eg. while subsetting and using certain build-in functions)

Answer (score 0):

There is no plyr actually needed for that. There is only `character` vector with names `id`, then there is a values vector relative to that names `a` and then there is some computing of third vector `sumb`. Like below ...

```
> id<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
> a<-c(2,4,20,8,7)
> b<-c(1,3,4,7)
> c<-c(3,6,9,12)
> 
> d1 <- data.frame(id,a,sum=sapply(a,function(a,b,c)sum(c[a > b]),b,c))
> 
> print(d1)
  id  a sum
1  a  2   3
2  b  4   9
3  c 20  30
4  d  8  30
5  e  7  18
>
```